# Javascript focus on span that is inside a div

Tags: javascript, html

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

span {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <span contenteditable id="haha"><i>asd</i></span>
</div>
```

I want to focus on `#haha`, but it only works if I move the element outside the div

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

span {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>

</div>
<span contenteditable id="haha"><i>asd</i></span>
```

Currently using this this code for the focus, if there a way to focus on the span element even if it's inside the div?

```
document.querySelector(`#haha`).focus();
```

Comment: What are you CSS styles for `#haha:focus`? I don't think span normally has any :focus styles assigned by default.

Comment: I just edited your question to create snippets, but I might have incorrectly reproduced the problem. Could you quickly make sure that your problem is still being reproduced properly by running the snippets and editing your question if necessary?

Comment: @Rojo Yes, the question is still correct.

Comment: I think you should add a tabindex attribute to it. Even though it seems to work for me no matter it is inside of the div or no.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `tabindex="0"`. It allows items which normally are not focusable to receive focus

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

span {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
span:focus{
border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <span tabindex="0" contenteditable id="haha"><i>asd</i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.getElementById("haha")` (notice I removed the '#')

> The Document method getElementById() returns an Element object
> representing the element whose id property matches the specified
> string. Since element IDs are required to be unique if specified,
> they're a useful way to get access to a specific element quickly.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

EDIT:

Looks like manipulating the tabindex allows this to work:

```js
myFunction = function() {

  let x = document.getElementById("haha");
  x.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
  x.focus();
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <span contenteditable="true" id="haha">asd</span>
</div>
<button class="bold">Bold</button>

<div contenteditable="true">
  whatever
</div>

<button class="bold">Bold</button>
```

Comment: I'm using document.querySelector('#haha') to get the element, the problem I'm facing is that I can't .focus() on the element if it's inside a div.

Comment: Both `getElementById` and `querySelector` return an element; The only difference is speed.

Comment: But I can't seem to input text into the span if I use the `tabIndex` method. It does not seem to be focusing on the actual span element, I added on `focus` event listener to the span element, it did not trigger when it was focused using the `tabIndex` method.

Comment: @allen - I am experiencing the same. Make sure you are testing this on your site with the browser's dev tools closed.  The dev tools can take focus. I'm seeing a lot of chatter on Google regarding that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add some text into the `div`. Then they'll each have their own content to edit.

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

span {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>div<span contenteditable id="haha">span</span></div>
```